# creating and array using type Big.Int and counting the sum of all integers inside it

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, golang, interfaces

Im communicating with a smart contract trying to get the balances from a list of addresses. I then want to get the sum of all balances but I am stuck on actually creating the array to store all the balances.. I need a type of big.Int but have no idea how to create it for my array. so far my code is:

```
balances := make([]int, 0)

for _, address := range getAddresses {
    getAddressBalance, err := token.BalanceOf(&bind.CallOpts{Pending: true}, address)
    balances = append(balances, getAddressBalance)
}
```

and the error i get is

`cannot use getAddressBalance (type *big.Int) as type int in append`

Answer (score 0):

Import the `math/big` native Go package and change the type from `int` to `*big.Int`:

```
balances := make([]*big.Int, 0)
```